# SAP R/3 SQL DB2 BOM Explosion

Tags: sql, db2, erp, sap-r3

*UPDATED*

I have the need to get a BOM with all components , currently using Tc. CK86 , but this doesn't give enough information, so I want to do this by SQL, I come from oracle background and dont know how could I get this done in DB2 R/3, I do not have access to query builder or quickview , but I do have read access via SQL, I'm currently trying to figure out a way of getting this info using tables :

- MAST Material to BOM Link
- STKO BOM Header
- STPO BOM item

Does any of you  have a solution for this?

In Oracle I did something like the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEVEL
    ,sys_connect_by_path(msil.segment1, ' @ ') AS "BOM TREE"
    ,msi.segment1
    ,lpad(' ', LEVEL, '') || msil.segment1 Cod_Component
    ,msil.item_type
    ,msil.description Desc_Component
    ,BIC.component_quantity
    ,msiL.primary_unit_of_measure
FROM mtl_system_items msi
    ,bom_bill_of_materials bom
    ,BOM_INVENTORY_COMPONENTS BIC
    ,MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS MSIL
WHERE msi.organization_id = 332
    AND BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID = MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
    AND BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID = MSI.ORGANIZATION_id
    AND bom.bill_sequence_id = bic.bill_sequence_id
    AND nvl(bic.disable_date, sysdate) >= SYSDATE
    AND BIC.component_ITEM_ID = MSIL.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
    AND Bom.ORGANIZATION_ID = MSIL.ORGANIZATION_ID
    AND msil.inventory_item_status_code = 'Active'
    AND msi.inventory_item_status_code = 'Active' 
    connect BY prior bic.component_item_id = bom.assembly_item_id
    START WITH msi.segment1 = trim(:parte)
    ORDER BY 2
```

I am trying the following, trying to keep it simple but it is giving me an error at line 18 no matter what I try , apparently in DB2 I need the "connect by" to be after the "START" , in my oracle working example it has "connect" first, don't know if it makes a difference, but no matter how i write it, it gives me an error :"ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/AIX64] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "PRIOR" was found following "ASQ19130' CONNECT BY".  Expected tokens may include:  "PRIOR"."

Here is what I got so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT level
    ,sys_connect_by_path(msil.stlnr, ' @ ') AS "BOM TREE"
    ,msi.stlnr as parent
    --,lpad(' ', LEVEL, '') || MSIL.MATNR Cod_Component
  --,lpad(' ', LEVEL, '') || MSIL.MATNR as Cod_Component
  ,CAST(SPACE((LEVEL - 1) * 4) || '/' || MSIL.MATNR AS VARCHAR(40)) as Cod_Component
    ,BIC.menge as qty
  ,bic.stlnr as compnumb
    ,msiL.mein as uom
FROM 
   MAST msi
    ,STKO bom
    ,STPO BIC
    ,MAST MSIL
WHERE 
BOM.STLNR = MSI.STLNR
AND BIC.STLNR = MSIL.STLNR 
START WITH msi.MATNR = 'ASQ19130'
CONNECT BY PRIOR BIC.stlnr = bom.stlnr
order by 2
```

Comment: Do you have access only to DB2 backend or can use SAP developer's transactions (=OpenSQL) too?

Comment: The DB2 manual [has an example](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059242.html).

Comment: Only to db2 backend.

Comment: @Suncatcher I now have access to SQVI, never used it before tho.

Comment: mustaccio thanks for your valuable comment , but I found an example also online in the ibm pages but it is giving me the error too, also the manual is not relevant to the sap r3 structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what ended up with and it works for me.

(Edited for bugfix)

in case anyones needs this:

```
WITH myquery (
    root,
    matnr,matd,
    bom_tree,
    lvl,
    parent_stlkn,
    stlkn,
    idnrk,
    meins, menge
) AS (
    SELECT
        m.matnr root,
        m.matnr,MAKT.MAKTX Matd,
        p.idnrk bom_tree,
        1 lvl,
        p.stlkn,
        p.stlkn,
        p.idnrk,
        p.meins, p.menge
    FROM
        mast m 
        JOIN stko k ON k.stlnr = m.stlnr AND K.STLAL=M.STLAL
        JOIN stpo p ON p.stlnr = k.stlnr,makt
        where m.stlal='01' /*and k.stlal='01'*/
        and m.matnr=MAKT.matnr
),x (
    root,
    matnr,matd,
    bom_tree,
    lvl,
    parent_stlkn,
    stlkn,
    idnrk,
    meins, menge
) AS (
    SELECT
        root,
        matnr,matd,
        bom_tree,
        lvl,
        parent_stlkn,
        stlkn,
        idnrk,
        meins, menge
    FROM
        myquery
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        x1.root,
        x2.matnr,x2.matd,
        x1.bom_tree
         || ' @ '
         || x2.idnrk bom_tree,
        x1.lvl + 1 lvl,
        x1.parent_stlkn,
        x2.stlkn,
        x2.idnrk,
        x2.meins,x2.menge
    FROM
        myquery x1,
        myquery x2
    WHERE
        x2.matnr = x1.bom_tree
        
) SELECT 
    x.matnr,matd Description,
    marc.herkl country,
    eina.urzla country2,
    mbew.stprs comp_price,
    bom_tree,
    lvl,
    stlkn,
    idnrk comp,
    x.meins UOM,
    menge qpa
FROM
    x, marc, mbew, eina
WHERE
    root  = :p
    and mbew.matnr=marc.matnr
    and mbew.matnr=eina.matnr
    and marc.werks=1850
    and idnrk=mbew.matnr
    --and x.matnr=mbew.matnr
    and mbew.bwkey=1850
ORDER BY
    root,
    parent_stlkn,
    lvl,
    stlkn
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated!